# how to add array of dates in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

good day, how can i add an array of dates with this example of codes:
All this data comes from my database query, i am using codeigniter for this.

and i have this query in my model:

```
SELECT 
  tbl_fdtr.id,
  tbl_fdtr.emp_id,
  date(tbl_fdtr.in_out) AS dtr_date,
  SUM(time(tbl_fdtr.in_out)) AS dtr_time,
  subtime(max(time(tbl_fdtr.in_out)), min(time(tbl_fdtr.in_out))) AS timediffs,
  tbl_fdtr.status,
  tbl_employee.emp_id,
  tbl_employee.emp_fname,
  tbl_employee.emp_mname,
  tbl_employee.emp_lname
FROM tbl_fdtr
INNER JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_fdtr.emp_id = tbl_employee.emp_id
WHERE date(tbl_fdtr.in_out) >= '$from'
  AND date(tbl_fdtr.in_out) <= '$to'
  AND tbl_fdtr.emp_id= '$id'
GROUP BY date(tbl_fdtr.in_out)
```

this foreach is in my view.

```
?>

var_dump($val['timediffs']);

array (size=11)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '09:00:00' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '08:32:00' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '09:21:00' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '08:22:00' (length=8)
  4 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '06:30:00' (length=8)
  5 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '08:42:00' (length=8)
  6 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '09:00:00' (length=8)
  7 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '09:24:00' (length=8)
  8 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '09:41:00' (length=8)
  9 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '08:46:00' (length=8)
  10 => 
    array (size=9)
      'timediffs' => string '08:54:00' (length=8)
```

> i want to get the sum of dates of $val['timediffs'];
>   i tried it in a timesheet calculator, i got the result '96:12:00'. so i want somthing like that.

Comment: @Uchiha, thanks for editing.. do you have any idea about this? in case

Comment: anyone? help.. im begging you :)

Comment: "how can i add an array of dates" - what does it mean? Add array to what? Do you want to make new array containing only dates or...? Sum of dates makes not much sense neither. Please explain better what you need.

Comment: $unique_date[0]['timediffs'] + $unique_date[1]['timediffs'] + and so on till the last key of the array. This is what you looking for ??

Comment: Its really confusing what you want to add actually

Comment: He wants to do addition of all `timediffs` values from array

Comment: @MilanG = i want to add the Dates(that 'timediffs' field up there), where i queried and now became an array using foreach.

Comment: @SameerK yeah something like that, but that only limits to [0] and [1]

Comment: @Uchiha: what i wanted to add was the 'timediffs' field values. i did it something like this array_sum($unique_date['timediffs']) but it didn't work. reason why i want this is because i want to know the total hours dhave S barsalote has been working on. its for DTR purposes

Comment: @aintno12u can you post the expected output

Comment: @aintno12u Do i give my answer single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$totalTimeInSecs = 0;
foreach ($unique_date as $timeArray) {   
    if (isset($timeArray['timediffs'])) { 
      list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(':',$timeArray['timediffs']);
      $totalTimeInSecs += (int) ltrim($secs,'0'); // Add seconds to total
      $totalTimeInSecs += ((int) ltrim($mins,'0')) * 60; // Add minutes to total
      $totalTimeInSecs += ((int) ltrim($hours,'0')) * 3600; // Add hours to total
    }  
}
$hours = str_pad(floor($totalTimeInSecs / 3600),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$mins = str_pad(floor(($totalTimeInSecs % 3600) / 60),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$secs = str_pad($totalTimeInSecs % 60,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "Total time string: $hours:$mins:$secs";
```

Comment: @Ra..esh, i dont know how to read that but tHaT wAs AwESOME..... this is what i have been looking for. Thank you sooo much.

Comment: Cheers buddy... And u could have simply copy pasted the name ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($unique_date as $date) {
    $sum += strtotime($date['timediffs']);
}

$sumTime = date("H:i:s",$sum);
```

Comment: Day(s)                   |    Total Hours
2015-05-01       |    09:00:00
2015-05-05       |    08:32:00
2015-05-06       |    09:21:00
2015-05-07       |    08:22:00
2015-05-08       |    06:30:00
2015-05-09       |    08:42:00
2015-05-10       |    09:00:00
2015-05-11       |    09:24:00
2015-05-12       |    09:41:00
2015-05-13       |    08:46:00
2015-05-14       |    08:54:00
Total Day(s) : 11   |  Total Hour(s) : 00:18:56

Comment: OM: that's suppose to be a table, btw: @esh it resulted to 00:18:56, why it was like that?